# $3(1-3x)^{-2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)3^nx^n.$ How?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I couldn't understand how I can get the following result on expansion:

$$3(1-3x)^{-2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)3^nx^n.$$ Any ideas?

Comment: In the form you have presently, the result is simply false: When $x=0$, the LHS is 3 but the RHS is 1. (The issue is the leading factor of 3 on the LHS, which shouldn't be there.)

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac1{(1-3x)^2} =\frac13 \frac{d}{dx} \frac1{1-3x} = \frac13 \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (3x)^n \\ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx}3^{n-1} x^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3^{n-1}n x^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3^n (n+1)x^n$$

Comment: @Semiclassical yes, thanks.

Comment: What is the correct solution. Let me know please. I couldn't understand it